# UITextView where should I set color and font for for attributed string

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

When I use UITextView in storyboard, I can select text as attributed string and set its attributes like color, font and other attributes. And when I set `textView.text = @"my string"` in code it show up as I set.

My question is if I want to do this in code, what would be equivalent to this storyboard attributes setting? From document https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/text I see some property i.e. textColor, font, but lack of some property that I can set like line-height.

Comment: What you can do in IB, you can do it all in code. In this case, you can use `attributedText` property to set what you could in IB. But if you use same style across the entire text, I think it would be better to just use the basic configuration like `textColor`. I don't know about the line-height. But you could just set it to `attributedText` if you could set that in the IB. For more advance control, there is *[Text Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html)*.

Answer (score 2):

This is done via the attributed strings object! You should definitely have a look at the programming guide:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html

Upon request, a short example to show how you create an attributed string.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //
    // Example 1: Create attributed string and set attributes for ranges
    //
    NSString *plainString = @"Hello World";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:plainString];

    // change the font of the entire string
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                             value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier New" size:16.0]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, plainString.length)];

    // set the font color to blue for the word 'World'
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor blueColor]
                             range:NSMakeRange(6, 4)];
    // assign to texfield 1
    self.tfAttributedString1.attributedText = attributedString;

    //
    // Example 2: Create attributed string based on html
    //
    NSString *htmlString = @"<p style='font-family:Courier New'>Hello <span style='color:blue'>html</span></p>";
    NSData *htmlStringData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *attributedStringOptions = @{
                                              NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                              };
    // assign to texfield 2
    self.tfAttributedString2.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:htmlStringData
                                                                               options: attributedStringOptions
                                                                    documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
}
```

And this is what the result will look like:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: This isn't a useful answer. Improve it by showing some relevant code showing how it is done. Otherwise delete the answer and post it as a comment.

Comment: No it's not. He was thinking, that this is done by sending messages to the UITextView or something, but it's not - it's done by the AttributedString object methods. If you click on the reference that I point to, there is an alway up to date example on the top of the page provided by Apple. Why do you think it would be better to copy and paste this snippet over here where it will never again be updated?

Comment: Because link only answers typically get deleted. Answers are better served by showing useful details, not just a link. It should show how to create an NSAttributedString and how to apply it to the text view.

Comment: Eike @rmaddy has a good point. I side with him, an addition to his comments you should try not to do this to limit [link rot](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) opportunities. Link rot grows as the Internet ecosystem does. Nothing wrong with including links, it just should be used as a reference instead of an answer

Comment: O.k. guys, I updated my answer and included a short example as a reference.